# imageSwap onClick via javascript not firing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

As can be demonstrated in the [following example](https://comfortoffice.iwant2go2.com/models/6/test)

A script that swaps images (generated via a Rails `<%= javascript_tag do %>`
tag)

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[

$("input[type=radio]").on("change", function() {
      var Frame_image = $("input[name=Frame]:checked").val();
      $("#Frame").attr("src", "/Mirra_2/small/Frame_" +  Frame_image  + ".png");
})

//]]>
</script>
```

based on source (snippet)

```
<table> <tr>
  <td style='vertical-align: top;'>
      <label><input type="radio" class='imagepick' id="Frame_6K8" name="Frame" value="6K8"><img src="/assets/Mirra_2/colours/6K8-f0d0fc886240ff430ef97b3f98ac23bf26f290b772bcb840460549cd61d15028.jpg" />Studio White / H-Alloy</label>
  </td>
  <td style='vertical-align: top;'>
    <label><input type="radio" class='imagepick' id="Frame_6K7" name="Frame" value="6K7"><img src="/assets/Mirra_2/colours/6K7-8052fe7aa605d525981035af0c1367d1d3808390b63bb29437f515cc63b58e8c.jpg" />Graphite / H-Alloy</label>
  </td> [...]
```

*note* the initial images are in the first section of the body

The javascript is not generating any errors in the console.  The images to swap for exist.  Yet, clicking upon choices does not lead to the image swap.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With problems like these, take the time to debug your code and see what is going wrong and verify that you are getting the results you expect at each step.

If you had added console.log() calls like these, you would have quickly discovered that you have no element with the `Frame` id.

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("change", function() {

      var Frame_image = $("input[name=Frame]:checked").val();
      console.log(Frame_image);
      console.log("#Frame");
      $("#Frame").attr("src", "/Mirra_2/small/Frame_" +  Frame_image  + ".png");
})
```

Comment: there is a `Frame` name.  My understanding was that that call was to the name attribute, while the `id` is the variant for that name, i.e. `id="Frame_6K8" name="Frame" value="6K8"`  id = name + value.

Comment: That is not how CSS selectors work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors there is no functional  relationship between name, value and id, any of them can be anything you want. However, there should only be one element with a given id per page.

Comment: Right.  Was entirely focused on the selector, not the initial image.  which had a bad ID identifier.  Thanks for the pointer on the logger; I was depending too much on the browser tools.